# Close exsisting dhtml iframe and open new xhtml iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, dhtml

I am using the below code to create a dhtml iframe.Now i want to reload this iframe with new url (or) close the current iframe and open new iframe with new url. If its possible means please help me to solve this issus.

```
var cust_id = document.getElementById("<%= hf_cust_id.ClientID %>").value;
var packagewindow = dhtmlwindow.open("googlebox", "iframe", "oldpage.aspx?id=Y&cust_id=" + cust_id + "", "Add More Packages", "width=1000px,height=500px,left=150px,top=75px,resize=0,scrolling=1", "recal")
```

I want to reload the old url page to new url page (or) close the existing iframe automatically and load new one.